# partially click through on layered windows win32

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, wtl

In using layered windows in win32 or atl/wtl c++ if I set the main window's alpha to 0 and paint on the child, fake window so that it is viewable and click the window, the entire window is a click through.
I want to be able to make only regions of the window click through, not the entire window, let's say if I want to paint a rounded corner window, I make the bottom/main window to be click through but I don't want the upper "fake" window to be click through, i want to be able to click on it. How do I do that?
Where I am so far:
In the OnInitDialog function of the main window :

```
::SetWindowLong( m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, ::GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
BYTE bTran = 0;
::SetLayeredWindowAttributes( m_hWnd, 0, bTran, LWA_ALPHA);
```

and when I create the fake window:

```
m_hFakeWnd = ::CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_LEFT
        , m_strWndClassName
        , NULL
        , WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED
        , rc.left
        , rc.top
        , rc.Width()
        , rc.Height()
        , GetSafeHwnd()
        , NULL
        , ::GetModuleHandle(NULL)
        , NULL
        );
```

IF, I set eliminate the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag the fake window is click-able while the main is click through, but! it doesn't respond to anything! click/drag. none.

Comment: come on peopleee! i need this!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are covering another window solely for the purpose of intercepting clicks?

Anyway, you need to handle window's [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message in order to be able to let system know that particular position is transparent, in which case you return `HTTRANSPARENT`:

> In a window currently covered by another window in the same thread (the message will be sent to underlying windows in the same thread until one of them returns a code that is not HTTRANSPARENT).

Comment: The purpose isn't to solely intercept clicks, I'm covering it so i'll be able to make a custom shape window. for example if I want to make a donut window i want to click through it's hole as if it wouldn't exist within the window.

Comment: OK, so I have removed the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT from the child-fake window and processed the WM_NCHITTEST message in the child window, so the lowest(main) window receives messages correctly but I can't receive all messages in the fake window, messages like WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN. what 's happening ?

Comment: so this is very curious, i have used spy++ to look at the messages the window receives, and does receive WM_MOUSEMOVE

Comment: Whatever you see with Spy++, you definitely have on the WndProc as well.

Comment: I GET WM_SETCURSOR in my WNdProc but don't get WM_MOUSEMOVE, i think it's something about mouse capturing.

Comment: Sent to a window if the mouse causes the cursor to move within a window and mouse input is not captured.  [WM_SETCURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Not sure I understand well, but if I would have to make a donut shape window I would use SetWindowRgn

Answer (score 0):

Make two windows, one with click-through properties and another with normal ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use alpha 1 instead of 0 in the regions you want to accept clicks. The window will still be completely invisible but the areas of alpha 1 will register clicks and mouse movements as normal.

Note that to get per-pixel alpha you'll need to use `UpdateLayeredWindow` rather than `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`.